# Showing items in a list with limited space

Tags: lists, controls

We have a list of items for a chart legend, and some other lists where there are items hidden below. We have several areas in the UI where we have a constrained space, and items that are hidden below.

Our current solution is that on hover there's a scrollbar visible, plus we have a white to transparent gradient at the bottom, so the last it fades, to suggest the list continues. We're in the process of refining this gradient...

[image]

There are suggestions and pressure (not from users!) to put buttons at the bottom to make it explicit that you can scroll down, but that is adding more chrome to the UI, which I don't want to do. We already have a good amount of chrome that's necessary, but I don't want to add more controls if possible. I am wondering if I'm leaving some other options on the table.

I'm sure people have come across this before. Any help on subtle (or other) solutions are welcome.

Comment: Is this list always big or it can sometimes have only 3 items? I think the size of the list (item count) must be taken in consideration before looking other solutions.

Comment: It would really help to know: 1) what sort of application is this? Desktop? Web? 2) Are you to support mobile or tablets? 3) Roughly what sort of target audience we are talking about?

Comment: 1. It is desktop only. 2. we're not concerned w/ supporting mobile 3. Our audience is API developers.

Our users are super technical. And I've not seen evidence in usability testing that people are missing the list items. That's why I'm pushing against adding more chrome to the UI. I can't show more of the screens (nda), but we have some IDE screens, plus analytics pages that use this device currently.

Comment: @Mike I'm not getting it. It's a desktop application and you want the user know they can scroll but you're not showing them an scroll bar? Why?

Comment: Hi rewobs,
Very sorry if i was unclear. We do have a scroll on hover, but I don't want to make it persistent, as some of our ui is very cramped, and we lose real estate to labels.

Since our users are advanced devs, I see no reason to not go w/ hover scroll, but I posted this in hopes of if there's any other devices I haven't considered. I'm trying to keep a crowded UI as pared down as possible.

Comment: It seems like an invalid argument to say that the ui is very cramped and that you lose real estate to labels when there is so much whitespace to the right of the rows that you are not making use of.

Comment: a scroll bar could be like 10px wide...could your UI not accommodate that? If it's so busy that 10px of scroll bar is going to overcrowd it i.e. the straw that broke the camels back...then maybe you should reduce the amount of content on the page more generally?

Comment: @MichaelLai Whitespace is not the same as _wasted_ space. In a cramped UI, a little whitespace can be very valuable. I can certainly imagine that a screen would look a little messier with a scroll bar there. The designer is in good company, since Apple decided years ago to also hide their scrollbars this way.

Comment: @Peter I am certainly not suggesting that whitespace is wasted space, only pointing out that you can say that there is no room left when there are still space that can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting buttons at the bottom and top of the widget is a bad idea. In my opinion that would signal to the user that scrolling is *not* an option, and reduce the discoverability of the scrolling feature. You have advanced users, and a complicated interface, so I'm guessing that learnability is not as important as efficiency.

Personally, I think your design is a great option. My first advice would be to **stand your ground**. Don't fix it until you know for sure that it's a problem. Do user tests, record them and show them to your boss. Figure out what's actually going of before you redesign on the insistence of some stakeholder who's overstepping his bounds.

If you do lose the argument, the best option I can think of is an extremely minimal scrollbar. Basically the OSX scrollbar, without the hiding feature. Use a light gray and show nothing but a slim rectangle. It should add almost no clutter to the interface but make your boss happy:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Show the scrollbar

**Usability must come first**, and the scrollbar is necessary to show users how to use the legend.

Once you establish the UX priority, you can then work to calm the layout.

Your legend has different colors, fonts sizes, font weights, shades, and difficult non-grid alignment.  All of these create UX clutter, which is why you feel like the scrollbar adds too much chrome.

**Instead, de-chrome the interface**.

Here are a couple examples of scrolling lists.  The left one is adapted from [an example](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html) in Google's Material Design.  The right one is a sketch for calming your dialog:

[image]